# How to translate PostgreSQL's `::FLOAT` to MariaDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, mariadb

I'm working to translate a PostgreSQL query to MariaDB and need help understanding how to rewrite this line in PostgreSQL:

```
   retained_users / MAX(CASE WHEN user_period = 0
         THEN retained_users
         ELSE NULL END)
   OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date")::FLOAT AS retention_rate,
```

MariaDB is not understanding `::FLOAT` - how can this be rewritten for MariaDB?

Comment: `::type` is PostgreSQL's custom typecast syntax. You can use the standard SQL `CAST(thing AS type)` in any database, including PostgreSQL and MariaDB.

Comment: @coladict that sounds like the right answer. Can you post the answer so I can accept? Thanks

Comment: Please don't cross-post.  The other Question has an answer involving `DECIMAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . is this sufficient?

```
(retained_users /
 MAX(CASE WHEN user_period = 0 THEN retained_users*1.0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY "Signup Date")
) AS retention_rate,
```